# when you change Format of the cells using "Format Cells" option then No excel event gets fired

Tags: excel, office-interop, excel-2010, excel-interop, vba

Can someone tell me that

1. If I have already selected one cell in Excel
2. Right click on it
3. Go to format cells options
4. Change the formatting

Then which event will be fired?

Please note that I do not move away from original cell through this operation.

Comment: no event is fired by that action. What are you trying to do?

Comment: No event will be fired by the actions you describe. Why do you want to trap this action? If you want to prevent the user from formatting certain cells, then why not lock the cells then protect the worksheet?

Comment: if the formatting is changed then I want to reset few varibales on my side

Comment: Hello @Philip , I want my application to understand that the formatting has been changed , for me if the user changes the format then it is as good as a new selection and my application is supposed to perform some new logic.

Comment: Excel doesn't offer that functionality.

Comment: If formatting is significant *and* you need to track when it changes using code, then you may have the wrong approach.  Whatever the user is signifying by applying formatting, it would be better to have them enter explicitly in a separate/adjacent cell.

Comment: There is no simple way to do that in Excel, Microsoft obviously missed a trick there!

Answer (score 4):

to be precise there will fire `Before_RightClick` event on the step 2nd but others steps are events-free.

Comment: This does not answer the question.

He doesn't have to right-click on a cell, he can select it (thus firing the SelectionChange event) then choose _Format Cells_ from the **Format** menu

Comment: The answer starts "to be precise" and addresses the specific steps in the question, so I'd say it does provide an answer to the question. @Philip's point is a good one though.

Comment: Philip, try to help, not criticise... you have no idea what is the goal of the action described in the question. My answer could be helpful, keep it as suggestion in situation where no other events are in place. Moreover, no SelectionChange event possible in the situation described in question- please read carefully.

Comment: I meant that in order to display the format cells dialog, he doesn't need to right-click, he (or the user) could simply select a cell then choose _Cells ..._ on the **Format** menu.

Comment: Sorry If the question sounds confusing , actually I start with previously selected cell/range , my goal is to reset my flags when FORMAT of the selection is changed and for that reason I am looking for some events. Actually I have already wired up SheetSelectionChange event which does reseting of flags but when the user changes the formatting in the way I mentioned above how can I keep a track of that if that act is does not raise any event ?

Comment: you can't without subclassing the range object in Excel, and believe me, you don't want to go there...

Comment: you could store the formatting the way it should be somewhere on a hidden sheet, and compare the cells against that when a selection change event fires ...